# VS Code Call Hierarchies Across Library Boundaries in a Monorepo

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, monorepo, call-hierarchy

In the context of a TS monorepo, VS Code appears unable to track call hierarchies across libraries. I haven't been able to find a solution in repos based on yarn workspaces nor Nx.

I'm currently working with a micro frontend architecture; because components tend to straddle multiple libs, a typical call hierarchy trace gets maybe one component up, if that.

I have no issues with any of the standard cross-lib IDE features - auto import / code completion / inspection / yadda.

Is there a configuration setting I'm missing, or is cross-lib call hierarchies just beyond what's supported?

--

Update 11/09/22 - Still no luck on finding an answer to this. VS Code's docs have limited details on the call hierarchy feature. Perhaps I'll explore the feature API and see if there's any hints.